# Did Jack and his crew come because they realised that the coordinates Walt gave probably pointed to money?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* season 5 Jack and his crew came to Walt's help even though Walt said that it was off. Did they realise that the coordinates pointed to money? If not, why did they come? I think this is a high probability because after the shootout, Jack says something like: "We have realised that it was a different way to give an address."

This question may also be expanded as: "Why did Jack's crew shoot Hank and Gomez?" If they indeed came for the money, then the answer of this question is obvious as well.

Answer (score 3):

You must see things as Jack would: he knows that Walt is chased by Jesse in the desert, he understands he is in big trouble but suddenly he says that everything is okay. The first guess would be that Jesse (with or without some help) has reached Walt while he was speaking and was threatening him, because if the police or DEA were on him (physically speaking) he would have had to drop the phone without having the time to cancel the order. At this point, Jack has specific coordinates and has his crew ready for combat, and considering their experience and their equipment, they can manage to handle almost anything that Walt couldn't. The only case where he would find himself in a bad spot it is if Walt is surrounded by DEA / Police forces, but he can easily tell if that's the case without exposing too much.

Then once he reaches Walt and he finds him arrested, he considers him too precious and dangerous to be left in the hands of a couple of DEA agents poorly equipped. Finally once he got rid of the DEA, he find out about the treasure and he exploits the situation.

Note that the shovel was not taken from Jack's car, but from Walt's.